# Why returning values from sqlite returns an empty array

Tags: android, sqlite

Im using the following code to add values to db.

```
public void addComplianceAcceptability(ComplianceAcceptability complianceAcceptability) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(KEY_ID, complianceAcceptability.getId());
    contentValues.put(KEY_COUNTRY_ID, complianceAcceptability.getCountryId());
    contentValues.put(KEY_DOMAIN_ID, complianceAcceptability.getDomainId());
    contentValues.put(KEY_UNIT_ID, complianceAcceptability.getUnitId());
    contentValues.put(KEY_COMPLIANCE_ID, complianceAcceptability.getComplianceId());
    contentValues.put(KEY_COMPLIANCE_NAME, complianceAcceptability.getCompliancenName());
    contentValues.put(KEY_COMPLIANCE_FREQUENCY, complianceAcceptability.getComplianceFrequency());
    contentValues.put(KEY_COMPLIANCE_APPLICABLE, complianceAcceptability.getComplianceApplicable());
    contentValues.put(KEY_COMPLIANCE_OPTED, complianceAcceptability.getComplianceOpted());

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_COMPLIANCE_ACCEPTABILITY, null, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

Imm trying to access the values using the following code,

```
public List<ComplianceAcceptability> getAllAcceptability() {

        List<ComplianceAcceptability> complianceAcceptabilityList = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLIANCE_ACCEPTABILITY;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ComplianceAcceptability complianceAcceptability = new ComplianceAcceptability();

                complianceAcceptability.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                complianceAcceptability.setCountryId(cursor.getString(1));
                complianceAcceptability.setDomainId(cursor.getString(2));
                complianceAcceptability.setUnitId(cursor.getString(3));
                complianceAcceptability.setComplianceId(cursor.getString(4));
                complianceAcceptability.setCompliancenName(cursor.getString(5));
                complianceAcceptability.setComplianceFrequency(cursor.getString(6));
                complianceAcceptability.setComplianceApplicable(cursor.getString(7));
                complianceAcceptability.setComplianceOpted(cursor.getString(8));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return complianceAcceptabilityList;
    }
```

The problem is that it returns an empty array. But when I try to print the contentValues within addComplianceStatus, it of course prints the array of all values.

Comment: You forgot to add it to the list :D

Comment: hahahaha yes! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never add anything to `complianceAcceptabilityList`.  You just assign it once, then do nothing to it before returning it.  Maybe you want to add `complianceAcceptability` into it at each iteration through the cursor?

Comment: i have added it to the list by now and now it prints the memory address and not the values

Comment: You need to implement a toString method on your object to if you want it to print something other than the default you're seeing now.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are not adding the complianceAcceptability object to the complianceAcceptabilityList, your modified code:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ComplianceAcceptability complianceAcceptability = new ComplianceAcceptability();

            complianceAcceptability.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            complianceAcceptability.setCountryId(cursor.getString(1));
            complianceAcceptability.setDomainId(cursor.getString(2));
            complianceAcceptability.setUnitId(cursor.getString(3));
            complianceAcceptability.setComplianceId(cursor.getString(4));
            complianceAcceptability.setCompliancenName(cursor.getString(5));
            complianceAcceptability.setComplianceFrequency(cursor.getString(6));
            complianceAcceptability.setComplianceApplicable(cursor.getString(7));
            complianceAcceptability.setComplianceOpted(cursor.getString(8));
         complianceAcceptabilityList.add(complianceAcceptability);          

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: now it prints some memory address rather than the values